# help calling a sub routine from a perl module and printing to logfile

Tags: perl

I'm not sure how to call another subroutine from a sub declared in a perl module. The subroutine is simply getting date information.

I have a file handle open for a log file and I want to print out some date information to this logfile, but its not printing out. I can see that it touches the file, I made the log file -rwx too.

Here is the sample subroutine in perl (Test.pm) module that I am calling:

```
sub spGetCurDateTime {
    my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime();
    my $currentDateTime = sprintf "%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
        $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec;
    return $curDateTime;
}
```

Here's part of my test code where I am trying to call the subroutine from (Test.pm)

```
use Test.pm;

#Create log
open (LOG, ">/home/dev/test.log") || die "cannot append";

sub get_alert {
   undef $/;
   open (my $QFH, "< /home/dev/test.sql") or die "error can't open this file $!";
   print LOG "Checking on status time =>", &spGetCurDateTime, "\n";
   my $sth= $dbh->prepare(<$QFH>) ||
      die ("Cannot connect to the database: ".$DBI::errstr."\n");
   $sth->execute;
   close $QFH;
   my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
   $sth->finish;
   return $row->{RESULT};
   print $row;
}
```

Comment: Use [POSIX::strftime](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod) instead?

Comment: @TLP there is a downside to `POSIX::strftime`, [it is half the speed of `sprintf`](http://codepad.org/V9hRTBQp).

Comment: @Chas Are you saying that we should not use this module?

Comment: @TLP No, just be aware of the benefits and drawbacks of it.  `strftime` does a lot more than `sprintf` does.  For instance, you can say `my @time = localtime; $time[2] += 24; print strftime "%F %T\n", @time;`.  If you were to try that with `sprintf` you would get an invalid date.  Basically, if all you want to do is format localtime as it comes back, then `sprintf` may be a better choice, especially if it is in a function that gets called a lot.  If you need to normalize a time or provide a nice interface to someone else, `strftime` is your friend.

Comment: @Chas I agree, sometimes using a module is overkill. However, it seems to be an SO pragma not to "reinvent" functionality that already can be handled by modules.

Comment: @TLP Using `sprintf` to format the time isn't reinventing the wheel.  It is a classic idiom that exists in C as well for the very reason I stated.  It isn't a matter of a module being overkill, it is a matter of `sprintf` being better for some things and `strftime` being better for other things.  They both have their places.

Comment: what is sprintf better for, besides running your benchmark code in 5 microseconds instead of 9?

Comment: ah; I wouldn't argue against it for that, I'd argue against it (in simple cases) for being yet another mini-language.  depends who the code-reading audience is, of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, never say `&functionname` unless you know why you might want magic behavior.  In general in Perl 5, function calls look like `functionname()` or `functionname` depending on whether you want it treated as a term (i.e. the highest level of precedence) or an operator (it is easier when you are starting out to just always use the `functionname()` form since that will do what you expect it to).

You can say

```
print LOG "Checking on status time =>", Test::spGetCurDateTime(), "\n";
```

But that can get old, so most people use the [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) module to export certain functions and variables into the namespace that said `use Test;`.  You may also wish to avoid using the module name `Test`, there is already a [module with that name](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test.html).

In the file T.pm:

```
package T;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw/import/;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/spGetCurDateTime/;

sub spGetCurDateTime {
    my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime;
    my $currentDateTime = sprintf "%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
        $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec;
    return $currentDateTime;
}

1;
```

In the file t.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use T qw/spGetCurDateTime/;

print spGetCurDateTime(), "\n";
```

Comment: `&functionname()` is never "magic" (though functionname() may be, if you include some of the more unexpected effects of prototypes as "magic")

Comment: @ysth No, &functionname() is magic as well, it bypasses prototypes.

Comment: @ysth But I was talking about `&functionname` which is really weird.  Not only does it bypass prototypes, it is equivalent to `&functionname(@_)`.  Unless you know exactly what you are doing, the only time you should put an `&` on a function name is when you are making a reference to it.

Comment: I don't consider bypassing prototypes weird, from the caller's point of view.  And I disagree with your conclusion; there's nothing wrong with a coding style that always uses `&()`.

Comment: @ysth There are many problems with the code that always uses `&` in front of function names: 1. you can't say `&split(",", $s)`, so core and user functions look different 2. bypassing prototypes is breaking a contract with the function definition (and causes confusion in new programers who expect the function to behave as documented) 3. `&functionname` unexpectedly passes `@_` to `functionname`.  4. You can't use `&functionname` as a list, scalar, or 0-ary operator. And those are just the reasons I can come up with off the top of my head.

Comment: 1. is a plus, not a minus (and probably the primary justification for doing it).  4. I didn't understand

Comment: @ysth So you prefer `my $mult = &reduce(sub { $a * $b }, @list)` to `my $mult = reduce { $a * $b } @list`?  4 is about being able to drop the parentheses and use functions as operators: `my @rand = (int rand 2, int rand 3, int rand 4)`.  In that case `int` and `rand` are unary operators (prototypes are what is keeping the first `int` from consuming the output of the other `int`s).  You need a good reason to use a prototype, but they do exist (e.g. 0-ary and unary functions, and functions that take code blocks).

Comment: @ysth And 1 can be a bonus, but only when you expect it.  If a user was counting on `my $sum = &reduce({ $a + $b } @list)` working, he or she will be very disappointed.

Comment: Chas. Owens: I personally prefer leaving off the &.  But one place I'm working for has a consistent policy of using & for all inhouse calls and Fully::Qualified::name() for CPAN/core modules.  It works very well (and dodges the prototype issue, so long as no inhouse code uses prototypes).

Comment: @ysth That sounds like hell to me.  Of course, if you are mostly using OO code it wouldn't be that bad.  In fact, a policy like that would drive all but the worst programmers (they seem to be able to tolerate anything) to use as much OO as they could, so maybe it isn't the worst policy in the world.

Comment: No, it's more like "Shun the OO, shunnnn"

Answer (score 0):

Read man perlmod.  You need to put the function as an exported symbol, fully qualify it, or import it specifically...

Answer (score 0):

One of the things many users don't understand about Perl is *namespace*.

Without handling namespace, something like the [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) archive of Perl modules would be impossible because each and every module would have to make sure that no other modules have subroutines and variable names that any other module has.

In the standard way Perl is written, each Perl module has its own namespace. That way, variable names and functions don't collide with variables and functions you have defined in your program.

Take a look at your Test module, and see if there's a line:

```
package Test;
```

in the top of the program. If it does, it means each variable in your module and each subroutine is in the namespace of `Test` and not your `main` namespace (which is the default namespace). The [package](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) command changes the namespace until the next package command.

If, (as we suspect), your Test.pm module has the `package` command, you'll need to refer to your `spGetCurDateTime` subroutine as `Test::spGetCurDateTime`.

As has already been pointed out, you can *import* variables and function names into the current namespace by using [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html).

```
package Test;
use base qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT qw(spGetCurDateTime log);

sub spGetCurDateTime {
};
```

In your main program:

```
use Test;
```

will automatically import your spGetCurDateTime and *log* subroutines, and you can simply use them as `spGetCurDateTime()` and `log instead of`Test::spGetCurDateTime`and`Test::log`.

However, default importing of all subroutines and variables is now discouraged since it can interfere with the user's own program without warning. In the above example, I'm not only importing the `log` function, but I am also overriding the `log` function that's built into Perl (`log` takes the natural logarithm of a number).

Better, is to use `EXPORT_OK` and let users select the functions they want to import:

```
package Test;
use base qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT_OK qw(spGetCurDateTime log);

sub spGetCurDateTime {
};
```

In your main program:

```
use Test qw(spGetCurDateTime);
```

Now, you can do `spGetCurDateTime()` instead of `Test::spGetCurDateTime`, but you haven't overridden `log` with out realizing it. You can still say `Test::log` to execute the `log` subroutine in your Module.

Comment: You have some serious syntax problems.  `Exporter` uses the package variables `@EXPORT`, `@EXPORT_OK`, and `%EXPORT_TAGS` to control what gets imported, not functions named `EXPORT` and `EXPORT_OK`.

Comment: modern versions of Exporter allow you to just import its `import` sub rather than inheriting; I like that much better

Comment: You're right. I fixed the syntax. It's been a long time since I've used exporting of functions. The preferred method is to use OOP Perl coding techniques and not to export anything.